# How to make String::Find(is) omit this

Tags: c++, string, find

If I have a list, which contains the 4 nodes ("this"; "test example"; "is something of"; "a small") and I want to find every string that has "is" (only 1 positive with this list).  This topic has been posted a large number of times, which I have used to help get me this far.  However, I can't see anywhere how I omit "this" from a positive result.  I could probably use string::c_str, then find it myself, after I've reduced my much larger list.  Or is there a way I could use string::find_first_of?  It would seem there's a better way.  Thanks.
EDIT:  I know that I can omit a particular string, but I'm looking for bigger picture b/c my list is quite large (ex: poem).

```
for(it = phrases.begin(); it != phrases.end(); ++it)
{
    found = it->find(look);
    if(found != string::npos)
        cout << i++ << ". " << *it << endl;
    else
    {
        i++;
        insert++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify: what are you struggling with?

What you want to do is check if what you have found is the start of a word (or the phrase) and is also the end of a word (or the phrase)

ie. check if:

- `found` is equal to `phrases.begin` OR the element preceding `found` is a space
- AND two elements after `found` is a space OR `phrases.end`

EDIT: You can access the character that was found by using `found` (replace X with the length of the string you're finding (look.length)

```
found = it->find(look);
if(found!=string::npos)
{
    if((found==0 || it->at(found-1)==' ')
        && (found==it->length-X || it->at(found+X)==' '))
    {
         // Actually found it
    }
} else {
    // Do whatever
}
```

Comment: my struggle is that I don't know how to drill into the string on a specific node.  I tried to write the code to test if the character before & after, but I can't think of how to do it.  I want to do something like it->phrases[found - 1].  I know lists don't allow the [], but I don't know how to dig into the string once I find it.

Comment: Sorry, I get your problem now. You can access the character using  ->at from the iterator

Comment: I was able to get it to work, thank you very much for your help!  Fortunately you had a couple typos in there, so it forced me to think about what you put, rather than cut and paste.  Thanks again!  Scratch that, you left the parentheses off on purpose, so you didn't have any typos.

Comment: Actually, one more thing... If you're going through text you might want to check for punctuation other than a space by using `ispunct`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize you only wanted to match "is".  You can do this by using an std::istringstream to tokenize it for you:

```
std::string term("is");

for(std::list<std::string>::const_iterator it = phrases.begin();
    it != phrases.end(); ++it)
{
    std::istringstream ss(*it);
    std::string token;
    while(ss >> token)
    {
        if(token == term)
            std::cout << "Found " << token << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated answer - boost::regex is a more complete solution, but requires building and linking.

Answer (score 0):

We can use boost regex for searching regular expressions. Below is an example code. Using regular expression complex seacrh patterns can be created.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp> 
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 
#include  <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  std::string list[4] = {"this","hi how r u ","is this fun is","no"};

  regex ex("^is"); 

  for(int x =0;x<4;++x)
  {
    string::const_iterator start, end;
    boost::char_separator<char> sep(" ");
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > token(list[x],sep);

    cout << "Search string:  " << list[x] <<"\n"<< endl;
    int x = 0;
    for(boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> >::iterator itr = token.begin();
        itr!=token.end();++itr)
    {
      start = (*itr).begin();
      end = (*itr).end();

      boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
      boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;

      if(boost::regex_search(start, end, what, ex, flags))
      {
        ++x;
        cout << "Found--> " << what.str() << endl;
      }
    }
    
    cout<<"found pattern "<<x <<" times."<<endl<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Search string:  this
>
> found pattern 0 times.
>
> Search string:  hi how r u
>
> found pattern 0 times.
>
> Search string:  is this fun is
>
> Found--> is Found--> is found pattern 2 times.
>
> Search string:  no
>
> found pattern 0 times.